# where to Download shp2sdo utility to process shape file to covert to oracle spatial

Tags: oracle, spatial

I am trying to load shape file into oracle database , i came to know that shp2sdo  utility convert the shape file to oracle spatial, can someone help with utility download url , i checked on Oracle site it's not available there ,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/esri-shapefiles.html#GUID-0FEDEB4E-5039-490A-83AB-1E226512A0A0) (for the 19c) version on how to load shape files into an oracle table.